# How to upload files in asp.net core web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I am trying to implement a file upload in Asp.net Core. See my endpoit below:

```
    [HttpPost("upload")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(List<IFormFile> files)
    {
        long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

        // full path to file in temp location
        var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

        foreach (var formFile in files)
        {
            if (formFile.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }
            }
        }


        return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePath });
    }
```

When I test it using Postman I get the following result even if I select any file:

```
{
   "count": 0,
   "size": 0,
   "filePath": "/var/folders/24/rmgj9ypj37709tnhxr2hgtfr0000gn/T/tmpX0SwbF.tmp"
}
```

Comment: Provide more information, like how is the request you are sending expected, which mime type you used etc.

Answer (score 2):

This should guide you in the right direction. The method is receiving a jQuery post object.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ReadFileHeaders(IFormFile file)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                // Now the file is loaded into the stream variable
            }
        }

        return BadRequest("File required");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem on the code. 
But when using postman(or similar) you will need to have the same name("files" on your case) on the parameter[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvaFC.png)